# Set focus to specific JSF inputText on page load

Tags: jsf, focus

I want to set focus on inputText field in JSF on page load. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you're already at HTML5 and JSF 2.2, use HTML5 `autofocus` attribute. In JSF 2.2 you can set it as a [passthrough attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm).

```
<html ... xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
...
<h:inputText ... a:autofocus="true" />
```

You can even conditionally set it, you only need to make sure that the `false` condition evaluates to `null`, otherwise the attribute will still be rendered. It's a HTML boolean attribute, so only its presence is already the trigger regardless of its value. When the value is explicitly set to `null`, then JSF won't render the attribute in its entirety.

```
<h:inputText ... a:autofocus="#{component.valid ? null : true}" />
```

An alternative would be to throw in some JavaScript. Every input element has a [focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.focus) function. The below naive Vanilla JS approach focuses the first element of the first form.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.forms[0].elements[0].focus();
}
```

If you want to focus a specific input element during window load, then do:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('formId:inputId').focus();
}
```

If you happen to have jQuery at hands, more fine grained checks could be done.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":input:visible:enabled:first").focus()
});
```

In case you intend to execute it only after a postback, head to below related Q&A:

- [Set focus to inputText on validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205604/set-focus-to-inputtext-on-validation-error/)
- [Calling a JavaScript function from managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675017/calling-a-javascript-function-from-managed-bean/)

Utility/component libraries may have builtin autofocus facilities. [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has a [`<o:highlight>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/highlight) which highlights all invalid inputs on postback and autofocuses the first one. [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) by default autofocuses the "last active" element on complete of an ajax request and has a [`<p:focus>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/focus.xhtml) for more fine grained control. See also below related Q&A:

- [OmniFaces highlight does not set focus with <p:ajax>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791392/omnifaces-highlight-does-not-set-focus-with-pajax/)

Answer (score 21):

If you use primefaces, you can focus your input like this:

```
<p:focus for="inputId"/>
```

Comment: Note that using this in a panelGrid will mess with the positioning... Place it outside... But then it seems to have to be inside the same form or something, so watch for that as well...