# How to check if a JSF UIComponent is valid in a jsp file?

Tags: jsp, jsf, validation, rendered-attribute

In a jsp file, is there a way to find a component on that page and check if that component is valid.

Say i have a an input field, and a panelGroup with complex html that should be showed if validation failed on the input field. What i'm really looking for is a EL expression for the rendered attribute on the panelGroup.

I tried playing around with a custom validator function, and here setting the panelGroups rendered value to true. But then it failed on required fields as the custom validator function was never run when this field was empty.

Right now i have avoided regular validation completely and use some rather ugly code to validate everything on submit. Then storing the result in a lot of instance booleans, which are used for rendered in the panelGroups.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [`UIInput#isValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html).

Here's a kickoff example:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText binding="#{input}" value="#{bean.input}" required="true" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
    <h:messages />
</h:form>
<h:outputText value="input is not valid!" rendered="#{!input.valid}" />
```

Note that the name which you use in `binding` attribute should not clash with the names of any request scoped attributes/beans.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is precisely what i was looking for

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, are you aware that `<h:message>` does less or more the same?

Comment: yes i have looked at message, however couldnt find a nice way of using it when the error message is more complex than just a string. Most of the error messages that have been specified to me have html lists in them or other html..

Comment: Ah yes, you want to display HTML in messages. Consider overriding the renderer. Also see http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/07/using-html-in-jsf-messages.html

Comment: Thats a relly cool solution, but refactoring at this stage is pain. 

I have run into a problem with the first solution you posted, #{!input.valid} seems to be false on the first page load aswell. Which means error messages are shown even though its not actually a postback, any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your problem. Which JSF impl/version are you using? I have tested on latest Mojarra 1.2 and 2.0.

Comment: Its JSF 1.1 under websphere portal 6.1, its ancient i know but a requirement

Comment: @BalusC If evaluating the validity within the inputText itself, do you still require the binding? EG conditionally adding aria-invalid attribute to h:inputText (via passthrough of course)

Comment: @MarkW: it's not necessary in JSF 2.x (note that OP was using JSF 1.x). You can just use implicit EL object `#{component}` anywhere within context of component. See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3140062 as an example.