# Calling a JavaScript function from managed bean

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

Is there a way to call (execute) a JavaScript function from managed bean in JSF?

If that's relevant, I'm also using PrimeFaces.

Answer (score 70):

### PrimeFaces 6.2+

Use [`PrimeFaces#executeScript()`](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/7.0/org/primefaces/PrimeFaces.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-):

```
public void submit() {
    // ...
    PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("alert('peek-a-boo');");
}
```

NOTE: works only when `submit()` is invoked by Ajax.

### PrimeFaces 6.2-

Use [`RequestContext#execute()`](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.0/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html#execute-java.lang.String-):

```java
public void submit() {
    // ...
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("alert('peek-a-boo');");
}
```

NOTE: works only when `submit()` is invoked by Ajax.

### JSF 2.3+

Use [`PartialViewContext#getEvalScripts()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/2.3/apidocs/javax/faces/context/PartialViewContext.html#getEvalScripts--):

```java
public void submit() {
    // ...
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getEvalScripts().add("alert('peek-a-boo');");
}
```

NOTE: works only when `submit()` is invoked by Ajax.

### OmniFaces

Use [`Ajax#oncomplete()`](https://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/3.6/org/omnifaces/util/Ajax.html#oncomplete-java.lang.String...-).

```java
public void submit() {
    // ...
    Ajax.oncomplete("alert('peek-a-boo');");
}
```

NOTE: works only when `submit()` is invoked by Ajax.

### JSF 2.2-

Best what you can do is to set the desired script as a bean property and conditionally render a `<h:outputScript>` component when the bean property is not empty.

```html
<h:commandButton ... action="#{bean.submit}" />
<h:outputScript rendered="#{not empty bean.script}">#{bean.script}</h:outputScript>
```

```java
public void submit() {
    // ...
    script = "alert('peek-a-boo');";
}
```

In case you're submitting the form by Ajax, don't forget to wrap the `<h:outputScript>` in another component and ajax-update it instead. See also [Ajax update/render does not work on a component which has rendered attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014/ajax-update-render-does-not-work-on-a-component-which-has-rendered-attribute).

```html
<h:commandButton ... action="#{bean.submit}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="script" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:panelGroup id="script">
    <h:outputScript rendered="#{not empty bean.script}">#{bean.script}</h:outputScript>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Will the omniface oncomplete work if the response header has a content security policy of no inline script ?

Comment: @Ced: Yes (provided the header is only on ajax response). I'm only not seeing how that's related to the current question. For future off topic questions please press [Ask Question] button.

Answer (score 38):

Depending on which version of Primefaces you're on you can use `RequestContext.execute("{js here}");`

From the Primefaces 3.4 documentation:

> RequestContext provides a way to execute javascript when the ajax
>   request completes, this approach is easier compared to passing
>   callback params and execute conditional javascript. Example below
>   hides the dialog when ajax request completes;

Code

```
public void save() {
  RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
  requestContext.execute("dialog.hide()");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Closest thing in Primefaces is;

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/callbackParams.jsf

Having said there is also an enhancement in 3.0;

http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1342

Answer (score 4):

You can't simply.

`Managed Bean` works on server and JavaScript on browser.

You can make conditionally invoke JavaScript depending on the value set in managedbean

Comment: Hi, I have not understand what does mean by conditional invocation i.e how can i call javascript function and i found similar functionality in richfaces with JAVASCRIPTCONTEXT.......

Comment: *You can make conditionally invoke JavaScript depending on the value set in managedbean* By this statement I meant that , you can check for certain property of managed bean and then take decision to invoke js or not

Comment: @Jigar Joshi   I am new to JSF and even development, I want to know how to invoke js method, To do this is there any standard approch available in primefaces. assume that condition is met successfully  in managedbean.

Comment: well in js function you can have `if("#{someManagedBean.someFlag}"=='true'){//take action }` ,

Answer (score 1):

In general, Java provides an API to evaluate a string using a scripting engine. This can be accomplished by javax.script.ScriptEngine and javax.script.ScriptEngineManager classes.

I am not entirely sure what your situation is, but if you can pass the javascript as a string to the managed bean, you could probably use Java scripting API to run the javascript on the server side.

For more information, check out this link: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html

Comment: Thankyou, Nikhil. I have fixed it in some other way. But its really good information

Answer (score 0):

I'm using IceFaces and I solved with org.icefaces.util.JavaScriptRunner:

```
JavaScriptRunner.runScript(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "<your_script>;");
```