# Open page in new browser tab from bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to open a resource into a new browser Tab  (like target="_newtab" for command buttons) from server side jsf code?

The following Code opens the resource in the same tab:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("resource.jsp");
```

I'm using primefaces. I think there is a possibility with javascript and icefaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution that I found was:

```java
PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("window.open('resource.jsp', '_newtab')");
```

Or when you're not on PrimeFaces 6.2 or newer yet:

```java
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("window.open('resource.jsp', '_newtab')");
```

Comment: Not sure how this can be correct.  I'm using PrimeFaces and there's no "execute" method available from the RequestContext current instance!  Is there code missing here?

Comment: I guess you are using the wrong `RequestContext`. Did you import `org.primefaces.context.RequestContext`?

Comment: Thank you so much, this was is useful for me, so if you use primefaces you can [Execute script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675017/calling-a-javascript-function-from-managed-bean) and call window.open script `org.primefaces.PrimeFacescurrent().executeScript`. Maybe this be help to somebody. Regards.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot control that in the server side. You need to control that in the client side. For example, the command button invoking the bean's action should have a `target="_blank"` on its parent `<h:form>`.

```
<h:form target="_blank">
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

Or if you aren't doing any postprocessing stuff in the action method, just replace that button altogether by a plain link.

```
<a href="resource.jsp" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Comment: i'm using a combobox for navigation and some elements should open in the same tab and other in a new tab. So a global target for the form is not possible.

Comment: Combobox? Don't you mean a dropdown? I don't see why you would allow one to edit the dropdown values pointing to other pages. Anyway, your best bet is then setting the form's target dynamically with JavaScript depending on the currently selected item.

Comment: Interesting.  <a href> method works of course (but isn't a button).  The form method doesn't work for me.  It opens in the existing window instead of a new one.

Comment: @Brian: Perhaps you're submitting by an ajax button instead of a regular button?

Comment: I do have AJAX components on the page, but this is not one, nor is it contained inside of one.  Does having any AJAX on the page at all result in this behaviour?  Ultimately I had to give in and use a commandLink instead, with a bunch o' formatting to try and get it close to looking like a button.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Icefaces:

```
JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "window.open(dir, '_newtab');");
```

where `dir` is the direction of the new tab.