# How to open new tab of same browser while submit jsp form

Tags: html, jsp

I have create one `jsp` page which contain  one `html` form while `submit`ting this form on that time i want to open it in new tab in same browser.

Comment: Do you want to get the response in the new tab/window?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231720/open-jsp-in-new-browsertab-from-serverside-code

Comment: target="_blank"  Opens the linked document in a new window or tab

Comment: `@Luiggi Mendoza` something like that...

Comment: @KamleshArya while the concept in your possible dup is right, I doubt OP uses JSF.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use :

```
<form method="post" target="_blank">
    //Your other code

    <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" id="btn_submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This will open page in new tab.
`_blank` is used for that.

You can also visit [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-css3-hyperlinks-20040224/) for more details about it.

**

> OR

**

```
<input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="window.open('http://www.domain.com')">
```

**

> OR

**

```
onclick="window.location.href='http://www.domain.com/','_blank'";
```

Comment: Yes I know I have just gave him a basic skeleton or structure that how he can do that..

Comment: Then please remove it because it may cause problems for future readers that don't understand this.

Answer (score 0):

try out this..

```
<form method="post" target="_blank">

    // form input fields goes here...

    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Note:** You can add action to form where you want to send your request.