# Open link in new window or tab

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

How can i open the URL in new window or tab when written the code in spring controller class.
Below is the code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView openDataLink(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors) throws Exception {  

    //logic to get or construct the URL 
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("http://www.google.com"));  
  }
```

From my application when i access the contoller, **google.com** is getting opened in the same window from where i'am accessing the application. How can i make google.com open in new window or tab when accessing controller form my application. Please suggest.

Comment: Relevant: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/49351-redirectview-can-i-have-this-redirect-to-a-new-window

Answer (score 1):

Opening a new window will have to be done by the browser via html (`<a target="blank_">`) or javascript. Java and/or Spring have nothing to do with this.

Comment: This. Also, you can set the `target` attribute to any string, and then all links with the same `target` attribute will open in the same external window.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this solution if you want to achieve this from the jsp where you are submitting form to the controller:

[How to open new tab of same browser while submit jsp form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487003/how-to-open-new-tab-of-same-browser-while-submit-jsp-form)