# call javascript from managed bean

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2

I want to clear form hidden value in JSF page from managedbean class .so i used to call a method in that i used this code to call javascript but it throws java.lang.NullPointerException below is the code.

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExtendedRenderKitService service = 
              Service.getRenderKitService(facesContext, ExtendedRenderKitService.class);
            service.addScript(facesContext, "alert('foo');");
```

the error is thrown in the line where alert is called .can someone help me please.even i tried to call a function in JSF page to reset values...it gave me same error.

Comment: At which line is the NPE thrown ?

Comment: @kocko In last line service.addScript(facesContext, "alert('foo');");..when i call javascript.

Comment: Not enough information. I am assuming that you are working with ADF / Trinidad. Can you provide details of how the form field is setup in your page? You can probably look at a simple solution like setting a partial trigger or adding the component from the managed bean code itself.

Comment: @user2644886........I guess you have to cast it as `ExtendedRenderKitService` Class as shown in this example.http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/trinidad/trunk/trinidad-examples/trinidad-blank/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/blank/HelloWorldBacking.java

Answer (score 1):

if you use primefaces,you can use Request Context component of primefaces.

[RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/requestContext.jsf)

if you dont want ,you can check this out

[without primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675017/calling-a-javascript-function-from-managed-bean)

Comment: JS is not executed

Answer (score 0):

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("jsMethod();");
```

`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("$('#ID').hide();");`

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('WIDGET').show();");
```

You can execute any javascript/jquery/primefaces code inside execute method.

Comment: JS is not executed

Answer (score -1):

You can use Request [Context component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml) of primefaces