# How and where to name a jQuery script to be called from a commandButton

Tags: jquery, methods, primefaces, commandbutton

I want to call this Script from a commandButton managed by a method in a bean,
where do I put the name so it can be referenced in a method? and what to put in that method?

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#pezz").animate({
                    left: '+=150px',
                    height: '+=20px',
                    width: '+=20px'
              });
        });
    </script>
```

it has to be in a method in the backing bean, because the Jquery will be executed if some conditions are meet, else other jQuery will be executed, and attributes of the bean will be changed...also other methods inside that method will be executed.

Comment: When want you to execute this script ? On button click ? From the backing bean ?

Comment: yes, when a commandButton, that have a method in the backing bean,  is pressed,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a JavaScript function from managed bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675017/calling-a-javascript-function-from-managed-bean)

Comment: This question is effectively a 'read the fine documentation  or 'use/browse the showcase'