# there is a way to call javascript function from prime faces

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I tried to call javascript function in my xhtml page by using RequestContext but I could not succeed it. Is there a way to call javascript function from view bean at prime faces ?

If the questions is not clear then I can provide code.

Comment: Do you mean you want the server to execute JavaScript?  Or do you want the browser to execute JavaScript that is part of the server page?

Comment: Hello steve i actually meant the server to execute javascript.

Comment: Are you calling like this: `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("yourScriptFunctionName();");` Also, which version of JSF / PrimeFaces are you using?

Comment: hello parskash. Exactly.  I am trying to call RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("javascript function"); I am usingg primefaces 6.0 and jsf 2.2.4

Comment: if still not clear i can provide sample code

Comment: did you see this post [Calling a JS function from ManagedBean ?!?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675017/calling-a-javascript-function-from-managed-bean)

Comment: you should **always** provide code if things are not working. See [ask]. And the code should be in [mcve] format

Comment: HYmm.... cannot vote 'mark as duplicate' of the question referred to by @YagamiLight... it **is** a duplicte

Comment: It is the same thread [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675017/calling-a-javascript-function-from-managed-bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675017/calling-a-javascript-function-from-managed-bean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Parkash Kumar said, you can call it from the bean, like this:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("alert('script called.')");
```

or directly from the xhtml:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{requestContextView.save}" oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)" />
```

Comment: RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("alert('script2  called.')"); does not work at my bean Danny. Dont know the reason work. But I am not able to see any alert

Comment: Check that there's no exception thrown on the server side. Also check your browser console for output. You could also use a `p:growl` to collect error messages

Comment: yea . there was a problem at clientside. that's why even it does not recognize RequestContext.getCurrentInstance() method . Thanks

Comment: There are numerous duplicates of this question and answer. Please next time search for them and mark a question as such. This prevents 'fragmentation' of knowledge

Comment: @Kukeltje not sure how this is even relevant.

Comment: @Makky: Then read the last sentence of my comment again an try to find in a search engine why Stackoverflow has the option of flagging and closing as a duplicate.

Comment: @Kukeltje I agree at some extent but I do see this problem on SO. A lot of people who have some knowledge feel everyone would have same knowledge.  As you can see soeone actually answerd and been accepted and I also found this useful.