# JSF - Return data within the Ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

I'm using JSF OpenFaces, and I have an Ajax call in a command button.

This Ajax call, calls a Java method, and it has `onsuccuess` and `onfailure` attributes.

```
<o:commandLink value="Save" id="SaveButton"
                    action="#{operationController.save}"
                    onsuccess="#Do something#" 
                    onerror="#Do something else#"/>
```

The java is quite simple:

```
public void save() {
             if(case1)
                  doAction1();
             else if(case2)
                  doAction2(); //throw new error?
}
```

What I want to do, without sending the event to the Java method (due to code\signature limitation), is to invoke 1 JS function in case1 and another JS function in case2.

I thought about throwing an error in case2 and then I know it will go to the `onerror` attribute, but I don't think it's a good practice.

I thought about putting an `if` inside the `onsuccess` but I don't know what can I check there.

What else can I do?

Thanks

Comment: When the user clicks the button: What exactly do you want to happen  on server side (Java code) and on client side (JavaScript code)? I don't yet get it.

Comment: @Selaron - thx - there is a general button that the user clicks, after the clicking, the `save` method invoked, and inside this method, the java code checks something generally (let's say - checking boolean var), and I want to invoke a general js function if this var is true and another js if it's false.

Comment: Other question: I had used OpenFaces years ago but it seames to be kind of dead. Can't connect to openfaces.org. Is the project alive somwhere else? Do you also use Primefaces or Omnifaces?

Comment: BalusC has written down some ideas on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675017/calling-a-javascript-function-from-managed-bean

Comment: @Selaron as one who used their paid version with the support, I can tell you that they died. no support, no documentation. nothing. officially.