# Primefaces start progressBar from backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there any possibility to start progress bar (ajax)  component from backing bean?
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/progressBar.xhtml. If yes, how could I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a JavaScript function from managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675017/calling-a-javascript-function-from-managed-bean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is pretty easy.  Assume your progress bar looks like this...

```xml
<p:progressBar id="progressBarClient" widgetVar="pbClient" />
```

Just run this in your Java code...

```java
PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("PF('pbClient').start();");
```

See the [Showcase Example](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml) for more info.