# JSF 1.2 javascript execution from java bean code

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-1.2

Hello I am trying all day to execute window.alert('aaa'); javascript from java bean code

I've tried all hints from:
[Calling a JavaScript function from managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675017/calling-a-javascript-function-from-managed-bean)

- cant use PrimeFaces 6.2+ because i don't have JSF 2.0
- cant use PrimeFaces 6.2- because I don't have JSF 2.0
- cant use Omnifaces because i don't have JSF 2.0
- JSF 2.3+ cant use because I do not have 2.3+
- JSF 2.2- does not work because h:outputScript is not used in JSF 1.2
- IceFaces JavaScriptRunner.runScript - cannot use because it automatically update jsf package to 2.0
- also tried FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getResponseWriter().write("window.alert('aaa')"); but does not work

Iam using this dependency and cannot update.
Also using richfaces 3.3.1.GA

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2_12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2_12</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Review the BalusC answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675017/calling-a-javascript-function-from-managed-bean

Comment: I have used all hints from that topic but none of them are for JSF 1.2